# iPhone shows album art but iPod classic doesn't

Tags: iphone, ipod, settings

When I plug in my iPod Classic to my car radio system, it doesn't show album artwork but when I plug in my iPhone it does. Is there a default I need to change?

Comment: What kind of car radio system?  Do both connect using the 30-pin dock connector?

Comment: Yes they do. Both work just fine with regards to music and videos. It's a Pioneer AVH-300 DVD receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Might have to do with how artwork is stored. iTunes can store it in the mp3/aac/whatever music file or in a separate database.

I noticed when exporting often the art is not included. A way to force iTunes to include the artwork in the file is to edit the file info in iTunes - like e.g. add a comment. Then the tag is rewritten with artwork also included.

Comment: How do you mean add a comment in iTunes?  Thanks. Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: When you right click on a music file you can edit the info - like artist, title, etc. there is also a comment field. It works with any field. But since you usually want to keep the title, artist and so it's safest if you just write a comment.

Comment: Should clarify that the artwork shows on my iPod itself, just not when it's attached to my radio. The artwork on the radio just shows the grey square with music note. When the iPod isn't attached to my car the artwork shows up fine.

Comment: My point is: it could be that the iPod supports the artwork to be stored in an external database while your radio doesn't support it. Or do you mean your radio shows the artwork when the iPod is not connected?

Answer (score 0):

After reading previous responses, most of my answers were taken. I do, however, have one more thing to add. Have you ever considered the fact that the iPod classic hardware just  may not have been made to show artwork while plugged into the jack?